# HTML/CSS - Navbar Dropdown UL not staying inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to design a nav bar for an upcoming project that I have an I really like the horizontal dropdown approach I took as opposed to a vertical dropdown that I usually use.  It looks nice and all but there just seems to be one problem.  When I hover over the "News" button (JSFiddle down below) as you can see, the third option just moves itself to the next line and I cannot for the life of me figure out what caused that to happen.  Is there an error somewhere in the CSS or am I using some tags in the wrong ways?  Thank you and here is an  example of the code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
        html {
            color:#ededed;
            background-color:#4d4c4c;
        }
        #wrap {
            width:1000px;
            margin:auto;
        }
        #div {
            width:1000px;
            height:100%;
            background-color:#252525;
            border-radius:5px;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 8px black;
            border:2px groove #353535;
            margin:auto;
            clear:both;
        }
        #header {
            height:150px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:red;
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
            nav {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right:auto; 
                text-align: left;
                background-color:#222222;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                width:1000px;
                height:50px;
                border:1px inset #131313;
                border-radius:5px;
                box-shadow:2px 2px 8px black;
            }
            nav ul ul {
                display: none;
            }

            nav ul li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }
            nav ul li ul li:hover {
            }
            nav ul { 
                list-style: none;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size:12px;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
                height:50px;
                line-height:400%;
                text-shadow:
                -1px -1px 0 #090909,  
                1px -1px 0 #090909,
                -1px 1px 0 #090909,
                1px 1px 0 #090909,
                2px 2px 3px black;
            }
            nav ul:after {
                content: ""; 
                clear: both; 
                display: block;
            }
            nav ul li {
                float: left;
                height:50px;
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;

            }

            nav ul li a {
                display: block; 
                padding: 25px 40px;
                color: #757575; 
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            nav ul ul {
                border-radius: 4px; 
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute; 
                top: 100%; 
                height:30px;
                margin-top:-10px;
                margin-left:-6px;
                line-height:210%;
                background-color:#252525;
                border:1px solid black;
                box-shadow:2px 2px 8px black;
            }
            nav ul ul li {
                float: left; 
                color:white;
                position: relative;
                text-align:center;
                height:30px;
                padding-left:5px;
                padding-right:5px;
                border-radius:4px;
            }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #848788;
            }
            nav ul ul ul {
                position: absolute; top:0; margin-top:30px; margin-left:-5px; line-height:210%; background-color:#252525; border:1px solid black; box-shadow:2px 2px 8px black;8
            }
            nav ul li:hover {
                cursor:pointer;
                color:#2967ed;
                background-color:#333333;
                border-radius:3px;
                text-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;
            }
nav ul ul ul li {
    color:white;
}
nav li:last-child:after {
content: none;
}
.space {
    border-left:1px inset #333333; border-right:1px inset #333333; width:1px; height:100%; padding-left:0; padding-right:0
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:69%;
    height:99%;
    background-color:white;
    margin:5px;
}
#right {
    float:left;
    width:29%;
    height:99%;
    margin:5px;
}

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home<img src="images/arrow.png" style="padding-left:5px">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Choice One<img src="images/arrow.png" style="padding-left:5px">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>TEST</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="space"></li>
                            <li>Choice Two<img src="images/arrow.png" style="padding-left:5px">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Third</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="space"></li>
                            <li>Choice Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="space"></li>
                    <li>News<img src="images/arrow.png" style="padding-left:5px">
                        <ul>
                            <li>News Page One</li>
                            <li class="space"></li>
                            <li>Second News</li>
                            <li class="space"></li>
                            <li>A Third News</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="space"></li>
                    <li>Forums</li>
                    <li class="space"></li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li class="space"></li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li class="space"></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

[Navbar JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ysY/)

Comment: It is too long, give the ul and li more width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `display:inline-block` from the parent `ul`.

This was restricting the width of the children `ul` elements to the width of the parent. Thus, when the child's width exceeded the parent's width; it would break to a new line.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sEMu7/)

```
nav ul {
    display:inline-block; /* Simply remove this.. easy. */
}
```

Comment: That has unnecessary space after the last option now.  You'll really see it if you look under the Home tab.  I tried this before but is there a way so that it just becomes the width it needs to be without the unneeded space which looks pretty bad

Comment: That looks much better.  It kinda sucks that now all the dropdowns are all the way left as opposed to starting right under the box that I'm hovering over.  The only problem I could see is say that I add one dropdown item to the Contact section.  The way you have it the dropdown will show up all the way under Home and it will be impossible to reach it because you will no longer be hovering over Contact.  I wonder if there is a way around this...

Comment: @user1895377 I've been trying to fix that. The reason for this being that the dropdown `ul` is positioned absolutely. If you were to set the parent `li` to position relative; then the dropdown would start where the current `li` is..

Comment: Yeah I tried setting the `nav ul li` to absolute and well..that kinda stacked them all which is definitely not desired. I'd be totally fine with the `left:0;` method if I could keep the dropdowns limited to the first couple of buttons, but I'd like a solution to it in the end

Comment: You are a hero my friend

Comment: @user1895377 Such a seemingly simple solution now.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your first ul.. the one containing all the links at the top is set to a width of 300px

when you have the dropdowns show up they need to be no bigger than that or they will break and give you that undesirable effect.

in your example since that third item is so long, its forcing the containing ul to be larger than 300px.

I just changed the parent ul to be bigger (500 px)  but you could see why this model could give you some problems.

```
ul{width:500px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2ysY/

Comment: Where exactly do I set the width of my ul to 300px?  Or is it set to that by default?

Comment: well its not defined explicitly.  the elements inside of the ul make it that size.  The thing is.  Since you are having the other uls sit inside of the parent.  they can never become wider than the parent.  Everything needs to define its own size and not be defined by its parent.  not sure if that helps =/